# htaccess Redirect for duplicate parameter in the URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, joomla

There are certain unwanted URLs which are having duplicate parameters. The value for parameters is 1 and 0 (both examples given below). I am trying to 301 redirect them to main URLs i.e. get rid of the parameter part.

**Example 1:**

`www.xyz.com/2012/04/bharati-4g-tariff-and-rate-bharati-4g.html?m=0?m=1`

redirect to

`www.xyz.com/2012/04/bharati-4g-tariff-and-rate-bharati-4g.html`

**Example 2:**

`www.xyz.com/2012/04/bharati-4g-tariff-and-rate-bharati-4g.html?m=1?m=1`

redirect to

`www.xyz.com/2012/04/bharati-4g-tariff-and-rate-bharati-4g.html`

**One short solution but not satisfactory:**
I had the solution where I could show 404 not found error for these URLs but later this  started giving me error in some admin pages in my Joomla site. The solution I followed is:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} m [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ /$1? [R=404,L]
```

Please suggest me solution which will give 301 redirect to base urls or will give https 404 not found header code.

The solution shall affect only URLs which have duplicate/double URLs like shown in example above but not other types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this redirect rule **as very first rule** in your .htaccess to remove unwanted query string:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^m=[^&]* [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}? [R=302,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the qsdiscard (or QSD) flag on your RewriteRule to discard the query string.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} m [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ /$1? [R=404,L,QSD]
```